# 'train' and 'class' have different lengths error

Tags: r, dataframe, training-data

I keep getting the "class and train have different lengths" error when trying to use the knn model on my dataset.

```
newDF<- newDF[c(14, 1:13)]
newDF
str(newDF)

newDF1 <- newDF[c(2:11, 14)]
newDF1

df_train = newDF1[1:47385,]
dim(df_train)

df_test = newDF1[47386:59231,]
dim(df_test)


train_lbl <- newDF[1:47385,1]
test_lbl <- newDF[47386:59231,1]
dim(train_lbl)

install.packages("class")
library(class)

newDF_pred <- knn(train = df_train, test = df_test, cl = train_lbl, k = 245)

CrossTable(x = test_lbl, y=newDF_pred, propchisq=FALSE)
```

newDF is my entire dataset, while newDF1 is inclusive only of datatype "num"

Where is the issue and how can I fix it?

This is the data:
`-10lgP`   Mass Length    ppm  `m/z`     RT  start    end `Intensity Sample 9` `Precursor Id`  range
                                                
 1   0.543  0.234  0.245  0.348  0.0310 0.543  0.234  0.245                0.348          0.0310 0.0254
 2   0.198  0.476  0.499  0.348  0.588  0.198  0.476  0.499                0.348          0.588  0.0256
 3   0.234  0.245  0.348  0.0310 0.543  0.234  0.245  0.348                0.0310         0.543  0.0255
 4   0.476  0.499  0.348  0.588  0.198  0.476  0.499  0.348                0.588          0.198  0.0254
 5   0.245  0.348  0.0310 0.543  0.234  0.245  0.348  0.0310               0.543          0.234  0.0254
 6   0.499  0.348  0.588  0.198  0.476  0.499  0.348  0.588                0.198          0.476  0.0256
 7   0.348  0.0310 0.543  0.234  0.245  0.348  0.0310 0.543                0.234          0.245  0.0255
 8   0.348  0.588  0.198  0.476  0.499  0.348  0.588  0.198                0.476          0.499  0.0254
 9   0.0310 0.543  0.234  0.245  0.348  0.0310 0.543  0.234                0.245          0.348  0.0254
10   0.588  0.198  0.476  0.499  0.348  0.588  0.198  0.476                0.499          0.348  0.0256

## ... with 59,221 more rows

The size for the class and train are as follows:
dim(train_lbl)
[1] 47385     1

> dim(df_train)
>   [1] 47385    11

Comment: Please share a portion of your data

Comment: I added it to the bottom

Comment: The structure of the data isn't clear. See if you get the same error with just a small portion of your data, eg 20 rows, and then run `dput` which produces a nice copy-pastable version of that data. Check out this link on how to produce a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you're unsure of how